# Qt signal-slot duplication code avoidance

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, signals-slots, qobject

I would like to share signals and possibly slot implementations among different classes, but it seems Qt does not allow this.

Basically I would like to have something like:

```
class CommonSignals
  {
  signals:
  void mysignal();
  };

class A : 
    public QObject, 
    public CommonSignals
  {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void doSomething()
      {
      emit mysignal();
      }
  };


class B : 
    public QObject, 
    public CommonSignals
  {
    Q_OBJECT

  public:

    B()
      {
      connect(&a, &A::mysignal, this, &B::mysignal);
      }

    A a;
  };
```

So that when for some reason A emits a signal B emits the same signal too. This to avoid useless code replication and improve maintainability.

Any ideas?

PS I've tried also with virtual inheritance but I've got classical qmake problems

Comment: You have a typo : `connect(&a, &A::mysignal, this, &B::mysignal);` will fix your error.

Comment: I've edited the question, trust me it was not that the problem :)

Comment: `CommonSignals` doesn't inherit from `QObject` and so can't have signals associated with it.  Do you not see any errors or warning messages from `moc`?

Comment: @Jarod42 You can connect a signal to another signal, that's fine.

Comment: @G.M. With multiple inheritance, only one of the base classes is allowed to be a `QObject`. So `CommonSignals` can't be one. Which means it can't use signals.

Comment: @G.M what I posted does not work, it was a kind of pseudo code to let you know what I wanted to achieve :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. `QObject` cannot be used with multiple inheritance of multiple `QObject` bases. Only the first inherited class can be a `QObject`. See:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first

Since you need both base classes to be a `QObject` (`CommonSignals` provides signals, it would need to be a `QObject`), you're out of luck. Your only option here is using plain old macros:

```
#define COMMON_SIGNALS \
    void signal1(); \
    void signal2();

class A: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ...

signals:
    COMMON_SIGNALS
};

class B: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ...

signals:
    COMMON_SIGNALS
};
```

The core issue with all this is that Qt uses moc to generate the underlying code for signals and slots. However, moc is just a simple preprocessor that doesn't understand most of C++.

You could use Verdigris to get rid of moc:

https://github.com/woboq/verdigris

This allows you to have templated `QObject` classes, for example. I have not tried it myself and thus don't know if it actually allows multiple inheritance. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm looking for some workaround because I didn't want to use macros, who knows, maybe there's some trick ehhe

Comment: how about using CRTP in some way?

Comment: @Saturnu The problem is moc. It doesn't understand templates. In fact, it doesn't understand most of C++. It just looks for a few simple things in header files. You can try and use this though, which completely gets rid of moc: https://github.com/woboq/verdigris

Comment: Yep I heard about Verdigris, thanks. Maybe I'll try that in the future, but I'm still interested in finding a solution for this problem. In some cases I managed to make templates and Qt work together though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just move the inheritance from `QObject` away from the derived classes `A` and `B` and into `CommonSignals`...

```
class CommonSignals: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT;
signals:
  void mysignal();
};

class A: public CommonSignals {
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  void doSomething ()
    {
      emit mysignal();
    }
};

class B: public CommonSignals {
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  B ()
    {
      connect(&a, &A::mysignal, this, &B::mysignal);
    }
  A a;
};
```

Will that not work for you?

Comment: This would not allow you to create, say, a QLineEdit (or any other `QObject` class not *directly* derived from `QObject`) that provides the common signals. I assume this is what the OP has in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Nope, this solution is not ok I guess. The goal in fact is to make B extend other classes, e.g. CommonSignals2, CommonSignals3 etc. As @NikosC. I don't think this should work for all the cases.

Comment: Ok.  I guess I misunderstood the question.